# Best program for syncing between Windows 7 Client and Linux Server

Tags: linux, eclipse, virtualbox

I work and develop PHP/MySQL on a Windows 7 Client. With xampp its simple to use and test. But since in my actuall project, I need some linux only features, I want to test my code in a virtualbox (Ubuntu Server).

Now I am looking for a good way to keep my sourcecode in sync on both - client and server.

I know, that I could work via SFTP on the linux client, but for me, thats not the ideal way.

I am using Eclipse and Git.

Any ideas for keeping the two filesystems sync?

Maybe samba, but there is the rights-problem... Rsync for windows?

Comment: Cygwin contains rsync, so I think you can use it. Rsync is probably the best solution, I use it for all my deployments (but I have only linux computers). Another solution would be to simply use git to keep your repository in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Samba is built-in to most Linux distros.  It's standard, it's reliable, and it's easy to use.

It understands your directory structures, preserves file names and date stamps, and use can use either Windows Explorer or your Linux File Manager GUI of choice (e.g. Nautilus) to drag/drop files between environments

What's not to love?

2) Here are some links:

- https://superuser.com/questions/258026/using-samba-to-share-a-folder-from-a-linux-guest-with-a-windows-host-in-virtualb
- http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susesambawin7.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSg-_3OFlrQ

3) If all you're interested in is keeping your source & version control in synch, GIT should be more than enough.

4) You can use a Windows client like TortoiseGit (or, more easily, just use Eclipse!):

https://tortoisegit.org/

5) You might also wish to consider using GitHub:

http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html

'Hope that helps.

PS: If you're using VBox, shared folders is also an option, correct?